# Развернуть необходимый блок

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть страница
http://denis-lev7.tk/sites/test/my_activity.html

В ней блоки, и кнопка свернуть сворачивает сразу все блоки, а нужно чтоб конкретно тот, который рядом.

И еще "свернуть" на "развернуть" меняется только после второго клика....

Помогите пожалуйста, что надо исправить?? понимаю, что дела на 2 минуты, но навыков не хватает!

Вот код jquery:

```
$('.turn-a span').toggle(
  function() {
    $(this).siblings('.main-turn').stop(false, true).slideDown(500);
    $(this).html('Свернуть');
    $(".main-turn").toggle("slide");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).siblings('.main-turn').stop(false, true).slideUp(500);
    $(this).html('Развернуть');
    $(".main-turn").toggle("slide");
  }
);
```

Comment: [toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) отменили начиная с  jQuery 1.9

Comment: ну я не понимаю что вы говорите, я не разбираюсь в этом. Мне просто надо бы знать что исправить в коде

Comment: я говорю, что ваш код устарел.

Comment: ну так и что мне сделать? я прошу чтоб мне помогли! то что он устарел ничего для меня не изменит!

Comment: так а какой помощи вы ждете ? Я вот вам подсказываю. Поддерживать устаревший код да еще и на волонтерских условиях мало кто захочет. Заплатите тому кто это написал, чтобы он поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй провести отношение.

```
$(this).parent('.dialog-btns').prev('.dialog').children('.main_turn').toggle();
```

Или, (не рекомендуется, но делают многие), при генерации проставлять уникальные id для кнопки и элемента и обращаться по ним.